# Not able to create IPA using xcodebuild command through jenkins shell script

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins

I am trying to create an IPA file using below command on Jenkin

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath export/MySampleApp.xcarchive -exportPath export/ -exportOptionsPlist export/export_options.plist
```

But it gives me error

```
    + xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath export/MySampleApp.xcarchive -exportPath export/ -exportOptionsPlist export/export_options.plist
2018-06-19 19:16:07.324 xcodebuild[81214:2060182] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/y5/1qdx7j6j2tdb1j6g3vvg_xww0000gn/T/MySampleApp_2018-06-19_19-16-07.323.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-06-19 19:17:20.872 xcodebuild[81214:2060182] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionPackagingStep: 0x7ff2b080be50>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionPipelineErrorDomain Code=0 "Code signing "libswiftCore.dylib" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Code signing "libswiftCore.dylib" failed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=View distribution logs for more information.}
error: exportArchive: Code signing "libswiftCore.dylib" failed.

Error Domain=IDEDistributionPipelineErrorDomain Code=0 "Code signing "libswiftCore.dylib" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Code signing "libswiftCore.dylib" failed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=View distribution logs for more information.}

    ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

I was able to create an archive file using below command

```
xcodebuild -scheme "MySampleApp" -sdk iphoneos -target MySampleApp -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -archivePath export/MySampleApp.xcarchive archive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="QPG8EMUULT" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="efb8da47-3b87-4880-82e8-4967167bb2d3" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keychain was locked on Jenkin server thats why it was not able to code sign.

Unlocked it with below command before `xcodebuild` command

```
security unlock-keychain -p yourPassword
```

Now its working good.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem when :

- `xcodebuild archive` using Xcode 10
- `xcode-select` to Xcode 9
- try to run `xcodebuild -exportArchive`

so I `xcode-select` to Xcode 10 and problem solved